# Javascript function not working in IE

Tags: javascript, html

This is working in Chrome but not working in IE.

HTML:

```
<img class="ortaresim" name="img1" src="Images/resim.png" alt="gezi" width="460" height="308" />

<a href="#" onMouseover="change_img()" onMouseout="change_back()"></a>
```

JavaScript:

```
function change_img() { document.images.img1.src = "Images/yemek.jpg"; }

function change_back() { document.images.img1.src = "Images/resim.png"; }
```

Comment: What is the error message? What version of IE? Can you provide a demo?

Comment: You can't have empty `<a>`, it won't work in any browser. When you put something inside the anchor, it [works just fine](http://jsfiddle.net/YdYhK/) in IE9 and IE8.

Comment: I should notice that tasks like this commonly implemented via [css] not [javascript].

Comment: @andrewpey I'd like to see a CSS, which can change the `src` of the `IMG`... (not a background in this case)

Comment: @Teemu nice notice, my bad.

Comment: I'm not taking a eror messsage just not working. IE version 9.

Comment: CSS =
.ortaresim { position:absolute;  }

Comment: This should certainly be in CSS, not JS. I've downvoted, since questions should contain a question, and demonstrate prior effort.

Comment: @halfer So, I'd like to see the CSS which can do this ; ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is not clear to me.If your code want to change image on focus on image then it should work with this.

```
<html>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function change_img() {
            document.images.img1.src = "image1.jpg"; 
        }

        function change_back() { 
            document.images.img1.src = "image2.jpg"; 
        }

    </script>
    <img 
        name="img1"
        src="image2.jpg" 
        alt="gezi" 
        onMouseout="change_back()"  
        onMouseover="change_img()" />
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Give the image an **ID** attribute like so:

```
<img id="img1" class="ortaresim" name="img1" src="Images/resim.png" alt="gezi" width="460" height="308" />
```

and change your event handlers like this:

```
function change_img() { document.getElementById("img1").src = "Images/yemek.jpg"; }

function change_back() { document.getElementById("img1").src = "Images/resim.png"; }
```